# If spending momentum to activate the Jury-Rigging talent for additional scenes, can it be spent as scenes progress?

Tags: star-trek-adventures

> **JURY-RIG REQUIREMENT: Engineering 4+**
>
> Whenever you attempt an Engineering Task to perform repairs, you may reduce the Difficulty by two, to a minimum of 0. If you do this, however, then the repairs are only temporary and will last only a single scene, plus one additional scene per Momentum spent (Repeatable) before they fail again. Jury-rigged repairs can only be applied once, and the Difficulty to repair a device that has been Jury-rigged increases by 1.

When I activate Jury-Rigging, must I immediately spend two Momentum to let it last two additional scenes or can I activate Jury-Rigging again at the start of the next scene and spend one Momentum to keep the repair working until I can no longer spend Momentum or no longer need the repairs to be kept up?

Comment: Is the current answer acceptable? If not I'll have a crack sometime at answering, once I've gotten trough the core rules.

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer: Yes, you have to spend momentum at the time you're making your skill check, and in the case of jury-rigging, you're going to want to.**

On Star Trek: Adventures Core Rule Book, page 84, "Saving Momentum":

> During any successful Task, any member of the group may spend points of Momentum from the group pool, which can be added to or used by any character in the group, representing the benefits of their collective successes. This pool cannot contain more than six points of Momentum.

Momentum is spent as you make your skill check, either spending through the extra successes from that skill check, or pulling from the team's pool, or a combination of. So If you don't extend the duration now, that jury-rig will only last a single scene, or until the next one. Meanwhile, if you did not accrue extra successes from your repair check, and if your team's pool is empty, then you cannot perform a Jury-rig, just a normal repair.

Since a Jury-rigged repair fails after the duration (Either after the current scene, or however long you have extended it), it becomes more difficult and costly to repair later. As the rule shows, trying to repair again a system that failed after a previous jury-rig, you're looking at a higher difficulty to repair it again.

Comment: According to the text given, it's not *possible* to jury-rig more than once.

Comment: That's right I wasn't reading it through. You can make normal repairs over and over, but only jury-rig once. I'll rewrite

Comment: I'm inclined to believe this is how it works, certainly makes more narrative sense and it would be rather easy to juice momentum to keep the repairs up.   But other than a personal interpretation of the rules do you have any examples, either from somewhere else in the text or a ruling from a more official source?   Examing the momentum section in the book does not illuminate the issue for me as again the wording seems to make arguments both for and against spending as needed.

Comment: Reference added.

Comment: I agree they would have been better off saying one way or another if momentum could be spent at any time. However, by looking at all references of momentum, they all mention it being spent in relation to a skill check. In part because they mention using extra successes of a skill check as momentum.